# NSIS Localisation problem

Tags: nsis

I'm having trouble with a Nullsoft Installer script.

I'm using the MUI2 interface with the latest (2.46) version of NSIS.

Just after the MUI_PAGE macros:

```
!define MUI_LANGDLL_ALLLANGUAGES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "German"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "French"
!insertmacro MUI_RESERVEFILE_LANGDLL
```

First thing in onInit:

```
!insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
```

The error I get is:

> unknown variable/constant
>   "{MUI_LANGDLL_LANGUAGES_CP}" detected,
>   ignoring
>   (macro:MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY:35)

Any ideas? I'm pulling my hair out.  the only help i can find through google is in Japanese/Chinese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time `!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE xyz` is used, it appends the language to a define used by MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY...

```
!define MUI_LANGDLL_ALLLANGUAGES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "German"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "French"
!insertmacro MUI_RESERVEFILE_LANGDLL

Function .onInit
!insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY ;This has to come after the language macros
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer.  The code appears identical to mine. Do you have any idea why I may be having this problem?

Comment: If I move .onInit to the top of the code I posted, I get the error, it needs to be below the language macros...